How can Chazal identify chukim as mitzvos that aren't readily understandable if the nations will be positively impressed by them?
Devarim 4:6 reads as follows:

וּשְׁמַרְתֶּם וַעֲשִׂיתֶם כִּי הִוא חׇכְמַתְכֶם וּבִינַתְכֶם לְעֵינֵי הָעַמִּים אֲשֶׁר יִשְׁמְעוּן אֵת כׇּל הַחֻקִּים הָאֵלֶּה וְאָמְרוּ רַק עַם חָכָם וְנָבוֹן הַגּוֹי הַגָּדוֹל הַזֶּה.
Keep therefore and do them; for this is your wisdom and your understanding in the sight of the peoples, who shall hear all these statutes, and say, "Surely this great nation is a wise and understanding people."

Chazal identify חוקים as statutes that transcend reason and that if anything leave non-jews scratching their heads (eg ספרא ויקרא י"ח
"וְאֶת חֻקֹּתַי תִּשְׁמְרוּ" – אֵלּוּ דְּבָרִים הַחֲקוּקִין בַּתּוֹרָה, שֶׁיֵּצֶר הָרָע מֵשִׁיב עֲלֵיהֶם, וְאֻמּוֹת הָעוֹלָם מְשִׁיבִין עֲלֵיהֶן.)
How does that identification jive with this pasuk?
(I am looking for something other than that they will praise them in light of the effect they have on Israel [as Malbim quotes from Ran] or as how Chazal seem to themselves be bothered by this and identify them as astronomical calculations [in B Shab 75a])


Moshe is using this word broadly to mean any law.
If the Jews are meticulous in keeping the reasonable mitzvah, and gain a reputation for going out of the way to do righteousness, the goyim will assume that the Chukot also have some esoteric righteous reason behind them.



keeping and doing them is considered "clever and wise", which seems to be the pashut pshat of the pasuk?

